# How to remove an element at the end and add an element at start in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Ok so I am banging my head against the wall, but am not able to figure this out, am making recent items list in PHP where I want too add an element to start of an array and remove 1 at the end after I've 5 elements in the array but this is not working

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['recent_items'])) {
    $_SESSION['recent_items'] = array();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['recent_items'])) {
    if(count($_SESSION['recent_items']) <= 4) {
        array_push($_SESSION['recent_items'], $script_id);
    } else {
        array_shift($_SESSION['recent_items']);
        array_unshift($_SESSION['recent_items'], $script_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `array_pop` and not `array_shift`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['recent_items'])) {
    $_SESSION['recent_items'] = array();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['recent_items'])) {
    if(count($_SESSION['recent_items']) <= 4) {
        array_push($_SESSION['recent_items'], $script_id);
    } else {
        array_pop($_SESSION['recent_items']);
        array_unshift($_SESSION['recent_items'], $script_id);
    }
}
```